# I need to add multiple contains assertion in my REST API test Steps using Groovy Script

Tags: rest, groovy

I have to check ever parameter of my response using Contains Assertion, there are approx 20 parameter. I added few using setToken(), but it's difficult to write this for 20 times. Is there any other method using which I can add all parameter in few lines of code?

I have written below code for adding few assertions

```
def addassert = testSteps.addassertion("Contains")
addassert.setToken("totalCases")
addassert.setName("Total Cases")
addassert = testSteps.addassertion("Contains")
addassert.setToken("numberofChains")
addassert.setName("No Of Chains")
addassert = testSteps.addassertion("Contains")
addassert.setToken("numberofOutlets")
addassert.setName("No Of Outlets")
addassert = testSteps.addassertion("Contains")
addassert.setToken("expiringToday")
addassert.setName("Exp Today")
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where are doing the actual assertions ?

Comment: I'm adding contains assertion to my test steps using groovy script. Wanted to check that all parameters are getting into the response or not.